# mod_rewrite not working when file is missing

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a rewrite rule in an htaccess file that I have intended to rewrite all traffic to the index.php file.

Unfortunately I have no access to root, and am chained to only have my webroot as a subdirectory: `http://example.com/my_root/`

The problem I am having is that when I try to rewrite

`http://example.com/my_root/account/login/` to `http://example.com/my_root/index.php`

It just gives me the Not Found response.

However if I access `http://example.com/my_root/` or `http://example.com/my_root/styles/styles.css` it works as expected.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" /my_root/index.php [L]
```

Thoughts?

Comment: If I go and create a folder in the path of /account/login, it works as expected and rewrites the url...

Comment: `RewriteRule` get path with `DirectoryIndex` that most likely index.php

Comment: So provide the `DirectoryIndex` info. If it has `index.php` then you have to precise your regexp for the `RewriteCond`. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/my_root/index\.php`